# 英語が残っている：ユーザーを編集：全てのコミュニティに反映

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

/users/editページに

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: @jmac 翻訳案がこちらにあります: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/28/30 (こちらは一旦 status-completed になっている)